# I want to click menu toggle then open menu

Tags: javascript

codepen.io/raihan-rony/pen/pOwQar

Check my code on CodePen

When I click svg menu blue area, My menu opens and closes itself, but I need to click menu toggle then it open and close.

Comment: Could you explain it more clearly? Now all I see is that you click the menu and it open and close.

Comment: https://codepen.io/raihan-rony/pen/pOwQar

Comment: Please add the codepen code to the question using `CTRL+M` button

Comment: https://codepen.io/raihan-rony/pen/pOwQar    When I click this menu any blue area then it open and close.  But I need when I click menu toggle this menu open and close.

Comment: Now I use Mobile.